# How to create smoke that spreads outward in all directions?

Tags: unreal-4, particles, effects

I saw many tutorials about smoke grenade but they just use volumetric smoke. I want to make something like the smoke grenade in PUBG, where the smoke spreads in all directions; how to do that?

The Unreal Engine 4 smoke grenade throws out smoke in a particular direction, like this:

[image: UE4 smoke grenade shoots smoke to the side]

But I want something more like PUBG's that spreads smoke evenly in all directions:

[image: PUBG grenade omni-directional smoke]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create a smoke particle system which mimics the behavior of a smoke grenade the docs provide a pretty good effect that just hast to be tweaked to your needs:

[UE4 - Niagara - Smoke Particle System](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Niagara/HowTo/SpriteEffect)

---

Key Settings in the particle system:

- Spawn radius from small to big over time - e.g. using a curve (to achive the pop effect)
- Sprite size from small to big over lifetime of the particle (make it seem like they fade out)
- Small random force upwards during the lifetime

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but to PUBG smoke looks either like very simple particle effect, or even worse, a bunch of "billboard" textures.

When you add a texture to the game in UE4, you can use an option "billboard", that means that it will always rotate to face the players camera.

If you are interested in why the smoke goes in all the directions equally, that might be related to lack of wind or just settings of the particle generator. There are a lot of good tutorials on that, just search "UE4 particles".